# Не останавливается таймер Js

Tags: javascript, таймер

```js
var interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;

function Timer() {
  sec++;
  if (sec > 59) {
    min += 1;
    sec = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("showsecond").innerHTML = sec;
  document.getElementById("showminutes").innerHTML = min + ' :';
}

function StopTime() {
  clearInterval(Timer);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span id="showminutes">0</span>
<span id="showsecond">0</span>
<button onclick="StopTime()">STOP</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Функция clearInterval принимает идентификатор, возвращенный setInterval.
В вашем случае вы передаете ей ссылку на функцию Timer, тогда как идентификатор хранится в переменной interval.

Рабочий код:

```
function StopTime() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```